# Trying to render a Context Provider in React, receiving error message "Element type is invalid..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to render a Context Provider in React with TypeScript.

Following code represents what I am trying to achieve in a very simple manner.

```
import * as React from "react";

public render() {
    let ctx = React.createContext("test");
    console.log(ctx.Provider);
    return (
        <ctx.Provider value={"hello world"}>
            <div>
                Hello
            </div>
        </ctx.Provider>);
}
```

As soon as this method is being rendered this error message shows up:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>       at invariant (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:118)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:20273)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29799)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690)
>       at Object.mountComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29803)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690)
>       at Object.mountComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29803)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690)

I looked the problem up in other similar questions, but all I got as answer was to update the packages.

My packages seem to be up to date with the following versions:

```
"@types/node": "10.3.2",
"@types/chart.js": "2.7.18",
"@types/codemirror": "0.0.56",
"@types/history": "4.7.2",
"@types/react": "16.4.7",           // <-------------
"@types/react-dom": "16.0.9",       // <-------------
"@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.6",
"@types/react-router": "4.4.0",
"@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
"@types/react-virtualized": "9.18.3",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack-react": "3.0.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "4.0.1",
"chart.js": "2.7.2",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"csstype": "2.5.3",
"basscss": "8.0.4",
"colors.css": "3.0.0",
"normalize.css": "8.0.0",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"svg.js": "2.6.5",
"svg.panzoom.js": "1.2.0",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"popper.js": "1.0.1",
"react": "16.6.0",                // <-------------
"react-dom": "16.6.0",            // <-------------
"react-hot-loader": "3.1.3",
"react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
"react-virtualized": "9.19.1",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"typescript": "3.0.3",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.2",
"webpack-command": "^0.2.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
```

Has anyone a clue how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `import React from "react";` instead? Why do you use `*` ?

Comment: @omri_saadon I do it this way as it does not work only with `import React from "react";`. It states that this Module has no default export.

Comment: Checked again, it is because it does not reference react directly but the types, as I am using typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself after hours of search.

**The solution was to delete the `dist` folder, which then was regenerated and everything worked fine.**

Comment: Thanks for this! I had some really strange issues after upgrading to React 16. The SetState callback wasn't ever getting called and this fixed it.